# Socket Client get disconnected sometimes

Tags: sockets

This is really drove me crazy and i don't know whats go wrong. I have a socket chat room, Server is written in `Node.Js`, Here is the step i do in client :

First, I create an object to connect to specific socket Url like below when document is fully ready.

```
  //create a new WebSocket object.
  var wsUri = "ws://164.x.x.x:9001";
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

Second, This method will log connection status as if it was successful connection or not!

```
  websocket.onopen = function(ev)
  { 
    console.log('Socket server connected...');
  }
```

Third, I have function to send some data to server in json format in order to append them in `#room_messages` to socket server.

Fourth, I receive server response through this method ~> `websocket.onmessage`

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev)
  {
  //server response
  //Here i decide to append what type of message based on sent data to server as i mentioned in Third Step above.
  }
```

And finally i got two other methods `websocket.onerror` & `websocket.onclose` which i log there too, Or try to create another object of socket but it wasn't helpful. Anyway,Sometimes it works fine, I got both the sent data log and `onmessage` loged in browser console, And sometimes i get only sent data loged, What is the problem exactly in your view? Sometime i get this error in server :

```
0|index  | Sat Aug 04 2018 10:41:20 GMT-0400 (EDT) Peer undefined disconnected.
```

But server still working without disconnection, Is it client problem or server?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client io.socket library fixed my problem!